# How to prevent method to be called twice?

Tags: java, android, function

I want to check programmatically whether the function is called or not. If it is called before, then do not allow and ignore to be called for the second time, if not then let button to call. Why i need to do this is because of i have a longClick button to run certain functionality, if user forgot to do this then however user will click another button which i will place the same functionality. I need to prevent running same function for twice.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{

private static boolean isScreenShotTaken = false;

blankcard.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

       if(!isScreenShotTaken)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
                isScreenShotTaken = true;

            }

        return false;
        }
});



btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent intent = new Intent(Templates.this, MailCard.class);
intent.putExtra("name", Name);

if(!isScreenShotTaken)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
                isScreenShotTaken = true;
            }

startActivity(intent);             

        }
    });


public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

// code exist here
//if called once, second call ignore

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

// code exist here
//if called once, second call ignore

  }
}
```

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: keep a static boolean methodCalled, initially set to false.
when called, check the value. if false, run method. at the end of the method, set the value to true

Comment: Related: If a user must not click a button, disable it. If a user must click only that button, disable all the others...

Comment: Stultuske can you please demonstrate it in answer then i can also accept it as an answer.

Comment: apply singleton desing pattern's logic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version:

I'd write it so:

```
// In the declaration section of your class.
private static boolean isScreenShotTaken = false;

// In the code.
btnsend.setOnClickListener
(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(!isScreenShotTaken)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
                isScreenShotTaken = true;
            }
        }
    }
);

blankcard.setOnLongClickListener
(
    new OnLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0)
        {
            if(!isScreenShotTaken)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
                isScreenShotTaken = true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: it doesnt work unfortunately. i click both buttons and both is functioning.

Comment: Only 1 button is shown... you must repeat the same in both buttons - I'll update my answer.

Comment: I followed your convention that one button works onClick and another one works onLongClick (WHY?) - if this is what you wanted. I would have set both in onClick

Comment: i purposely put one in onLongClick. any issue with that?

Comment: No, just curious - if the click doesn't take the screenshot too, it's OK.

Comment: Btw i just notice that; if i press onLongClick and after that press also save button click then function is not called twice which is ok. but if i dont use longClick one and directly use only save button then function is not called at all? why this issue? thx

Comment: blankcard fires at onLongClick. btnsend fires at onClick... is there another button that should fire onClick?

Comment: no only this 2 button. but i have return false: after onLongClick which is related with click. can he cause this? i demonstrate now in my question.

Comment: It should make no difference. It's just a return, since onLongClick must return a boolean. It's never used. Try setting it to true, but I expect no change. When you start you app, try clicking Send immediately., then long click on blankcard. It should fire on send click and not on blankcard long click

Comment: can you check my updated question. is that allright?

Comment: No, it's not... you miss some lines of code in the onLongClick Listener: `@Override public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {...}`

Comment: what i am missing? actually the way you declare listener and i set is different. but for syntax there shouldnt be any that i am missing.

Comment: Its ok i solved the issue. In onLongClick i removed the if since send changes to another activity there is no chance to call function twice. thx for all.

Comment: The code you have shown won't work as of the onLongClick listener. The onClick will.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a global flag variable??
something like,

```
btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    if(flag == true)
  {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//          Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
//          saveBitmap(bitmap);

            flag = 1;

    }
  }
});
```

So even though setOnClickListener is called, it wont execute the code within.

Comment: Firstly, make it `boolean`, secondly, change case to `flag` and finally, format your code! Using numbers instead of `boolean`s is old-C style.

Comment: I'd use a boolean, instead. And with a more "talkative" name, say isScreenShotTaken

Comment: but you hide both method in here. is that accidentally?

Comment: By the way, your should either remove all the "wrapper"-code (like `...setOnClickListener (new View()....`) or make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
// before start
blankcard.setEnabled(false);
btnsend.setEnabled(false);

// do your sutff
... here ...

// at the end
blankcard.setEnabled(true);
btnsend.setEnabled(true);

}
```

if you're using an AsyncTask or similar, put those calls in preExecute and postExecute

Comment: im confused with your before start and at the end things.

Comment: It's just a comment, not really important. It's like: "before we start what this method is supposed to do, let's adjust the UI" and "after we finish what the method is supposed to do, let's fix the UI". Ps.: if you don't want the method to never ever be executed again don't re-enable. What I've show is to not execute, while there's already one execution going

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button

once the button is pressed on .. In onclickListener

```
button.setclickable(false);
```

then button can't be pressed .

and if you have some method. than take a gloabal boolean variable
`boolean isFirstTime= false;`

and once you get into the method set it to true;

```
 isFirstTime= true;
```

Comment: this is not the same button so setting it unclickable doesnt help me. it is all about method being called. i want method to be used once only.